# NPM uninstalls unrelated packages when updating another

Tags: npm

I have a single package that I install updates for occasionally. All the other packages I'm fine with. However, upon installing a new package, NPM always removes `exif-js` and `angularsortablejs` packages from my library, therefore breaking my project which relies on those two. As a temporary fix, I thankfully have those stored in a node modules back up. I copy the folders back across to the project and it works fine.

Going forward, how do I update individual packages so that NPM doesn't feel the need to remove, what I believe to be, unrelated packages?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.6.0",
  },
```

Note, `exif-js` isn't listed in the dependencies, it's used be a script in the assets by using `var _exifJs = require('exif-js');`

Comment: Are those two libraries also listed in your package.json? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the response. Updated. Also, was the downvote simply because I didn't state that the package was listed in the dependencies?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. I don't understand the cause but am able to get around it by listing the packages that are removed along with the one I am trying to install: npm install <package-i-want> <package-that-gets-uninstalled-if-not-listed-here>